# Как изменить только день в заданной дате JS

Tags: javascript, дата

Всем привет! Хочу изменить в переменной time только день, но меняется все, что перечислено в условиях до смены дня - год и месяц. Я неверно задаю условия? Может лучше использовать Switch?  Помогите понять в чем дело.

```js
function changeTime() {
 var time = new Date("2005-09-07 13:45");
 var year = time.getFullYear();
 var month = time.getMonth()+1;
 var day = time.getDate()
 var hours = time.getHours()
 var minutes = time.getMinutes();
    return {
    add: function(number, unit){
          var plusYear = time.setYear(year+number);
          var plusMonth = time.setMonth(month+number);
          var plusDate = time.setDate(day+number);
          var plusHours = time.setHours(hours+number);
          var plusMinutes = time.setMinutes(minutes+number);

      
      if (unit === "year"){return set(plusYear)}
      else if(unit === "months"){return set(plusMonth)}
      else if(unit === "days"){return set(plusDate)}
      else if(unit === "hours"){return set(plusHours)}
      else if(unit === "minutes"){return set(plusMinutes)}
      
   function set(unitToChange){return new Date(unitToChange).toLocaleString()}
     }
  }
  }

console.log(changeTime().add(2, "days"))  // Ожидаю: "09.09.2005 13:45" --> Получаю: "09.12.2007, 13:45:00"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Столько ошибок, что даже не знаю с чего начать.

1. Методы `Date.setXXX()` модифицируют **текущий** объект. О том, что они что-то возвращают, документация умалчивает. Хотя вроде для `setDate()` написано, что он возвращает количество миллисекунд прошедших с эпохи Unix для новой даты
2. Зачем вы увеличиваете на единицу месяц

   ```js
   var month = time.getMonth()+1;
   ```

   для меня загадка.

Итого, если метод `add()` должен модифицировать дату в объекте, а потом вернуть ее строковое представление, то код должен быть таким

```js
function changeTime() {
  var time = new Date("2005-09-07 13:45");
  return {
    add: function(number, unit) {
      switch (unit) {
        case "year":
          time.setFullYear(time.getFullYear() + number);
          break;
        case "months":
          time.setMonth(time.getMonth() + number);
          break;
        case "days":
          time.setDate(time.getDate() + number);
          break;
        case "hours":
          time.setHours(time.getHours() + number);
          break;
        case "minutes":
          time.setMinutes(time.getMinutes() + number);
          break;
      }
      return time.toLocaleString();
    }
  }
}

console.log(changeTime().add(2, "days"));
```

Если же внутренний объект изменяться не должен, то код должен быть таким

```js
function changeTime() {
  var time = new Date("2005-09-07 13:45");
  return {
    add: function(number, unit) {
      const res = new Date(time);
      switch (unit) {
        case "year":
          res.setFullYear(res.getFullYear() + number);
          break;
        case "months":
          res.setMonth(res.getMonth() + number);
          break;
        case "days":
          res.setDate(res.getDate() + number);
          break;
        case "hours":
          res.setHours(res.getHours() + number);
          break;
        case "minutes":
          res.setMinutes(res.getMinutes() + number);
          break;
      }
      return res.toLocaleString();
    }
  }
}

console.log(changeTime().add(2, "days"));
```

Comment: Спасибо! А "Столько ошибок" - это те две, что вы перечислили? Забылас+1 удалить)